# How Would I Make Multiple HTML Tags In JQuery Using a For Loop?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamic

I am trying to make a dynamic option list using JQuery, though when I run the code, only one option tag out of n option tags (n being any real positive integer). Here is an example array:

My Code:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:3006/search', function(data){
   alert(data.names.length);
   var i;
   var arrLen = data.names.length; //In this case, the names array up top
   for(i = 3; i < arrLen; i++){
      $('#name').append($('<option></option>').text(data.names[i][0]).val(data.names[i][0]));
   }
});
```

I keep getting the very last option tag in the array, but nothing else...

Comment: You've set `i=3` so you are asking the for loop to skip the first 3 entries

Comment: I just realized that, it was from previous testing... Thank you! I feel silly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few issues here. Firstly the main problem is that you set `i = 3` in your loop, so you start from the 4th element of the array, not the first.

Secondly the correct jQuery method is `val()`, not `value()`, and you need to chain that call with `text()` on the first `append()`, not create two separate `option` elements. Try this:

```js
let data = {
  names: ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'Stephan Doe', 'Emily Doe']
}

// in your AJAX callback:
for (var i = 0; i < data.names.length; i++) {
  $('#name').append($('<option></option>').text(data.names[i]).val(data.names[i]));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="name"></select>
```

As an aside note that you can improve performance of the code by using `map()` to create an array of HTML strings to append to the DOM once instead of creating a brand new jQuery object which gets appended to the DOM in each iteration of the loop:

```js
let data = {
  names: ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe', 'Stephan Doe', 'Emily Doe']
}

// in your AJAX callback:
let options = data.names.map(n => `<option value="${n}">${n}</option>`);
$('#name').append(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="name"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code. May it will help you
HTML PART:-

```
<select id="main"></select>
```

JS PART:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let main = $("#main");
  let optionText = ['Option1','Option2','Option3'];

  optionText.forEach(index => {
    let html = `<option>${index}</option>`;
    main.append(html);
  });
});
```